# Ensuring a val is initialised in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following method in Java:

```
public void doSomething() {
    final boolean promote = false;
    final String bob;

    if (promote) {
        try(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            sw.write("this is a test");
            bob = sw.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    } else {
        bob = "anaconda";
    }

    System.out.println(bob);
}
```

When I convert this to Kotlin:

```
    val promote = false
    val bob: String

    if (promote) {
        try {
            StringWriter().use { sw ->
                sw.write("this is a test")
                bob = sw.toString()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    } else {
        bob = "anaconda"
    }

    println(bob)
```

But I get a compiler error on the last line: `Variable 'bob' must be initialized.`

I can't see how Kotlin could fail to initialise the `bob` variable when the Java compiler is so sure that the variable has either been initialised or an exception has been thrown.

Is my only option to change `bob` to a `var` and initialise it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assign the result of [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) method to the variable like so:

```
bob = StringWriter().use { sw ->
    sw.write("this is a test")
    sw.toString()
}
```

The Java compiler is able to figure out that the variable will be initialised because the [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is a language feature. The `use` method on the other hand is a library feature with behavior dependent on the implementation that is actually imported and used. In other words the Kotlin compiler has no way of knowing if the function passed as an argument to `use` will be invoked immediately or not.

Comment: Well, since use is inlined, the compiler will know that IF the passed function is invoked, that will happen immediately.

Comment: @Rocoty Note that the fact that `use` is inlined depends on the library that provides the function (stdlib in this case). Imagine an implementation like:
`inline fun <T : AutoCloseable, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R? { if(otherFunc()) { block(this) } } else { null }`. Depending if `otherFunc()` is inlined the compiler could try to figure out things further but it becomes complicated really quickly.